# How wave vector direction is opposite to energy flow in meta-material?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, refraction, maxwell-equations

I can see mathematically the in negative refractive index meta-material the direction of wave vector is opposite to the energy flow. Mathematically it is fine but I want to have physical meaning? For example what is wave vector without energy? What is propagating in the direction of wave? Is there momentum associated in the direction of the wave?

Comment: relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector#Direction_of_the_wave_vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to look at wave propagation: In terms of wave fronts and in terms of energy flow.

The former is described by the wave vector, and it's associated with phase velocity and field momentum.

The latter is described by the Poynting vector, and it's associated with group velocity and energy flux.

In terms of the stress-energy tensor, this is the difference between the $T^{0i}$ (momentum density) and $T^{i0}$ (energy flux) components. Within a medium, electromagnetic stress-energy is not necessarily symmetric - only the total stress-energy needs to be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  How can we perceive energy propagation direction is different then momentum? Which principle or idea can explain the existence of the difference? Would you please comment?

Comment: @Creator: amplitudes matter for energy transfer, not just phase